# Force Angular Material sidenav redraw

Tags: angular

I have a page with two [Angular Material sidenavs](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api). But the website's css contains @media query

```
@media (max-width: 1440px) {
    mat-sidenav {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

So, when the screen width changes without page reload, I observe a margin between the content and the sidenav, because the sidenav width became smaller:
[image]

I should be able to detect changes with MediaMatcher:

```
import {MediaMatcher} from '@angular/cdk/layout';
```

But how is it possible to trigger sidenav redraw from the angular component?

Answer (score 1):

I use [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) to provide menu item labels in the user's chosen language.  Because changing language affects the width of the content in the sidenav, this caused the sidenav to overlap the main content.  I fixed this by adding [sidenav autosizing](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#resizing-an-open-sidenav).  Note that it comes with a use **at your own risk** warning.  I chose to accept the risk because I didn't find an alternative working solution nor any issues during my own testing.

> <mat-sidenav-container **autosize**>

I also tried,

- forcing a page reload by navigating to the same route; gets complicated because by default navigating to the same route does nothing
- toggling the sidenav twice; to quickly open and close and therefore force recalculation.